# Azure Devops Board - Bugs missing

Tags: azure-devops, agile

I have some bugs that has gone from my Azure Board during Sprint.

Do you know whether is possible to track users using audit logs in Azure Projects?

Comment: Do you have the ID that you suspect was moved or deleted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Under Boards > Work Items there is a Recycle Bin section that contains deleted work items, including bugs.

[image: DevOps Work Items]

On the work item itself will contain the audit logs under the History.

Comment: Great, Joel! Following your path along the tool I could find. Many thanks!!!

Comment: Great! If this helped you then you could mark the answer as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

The question isn’t very clear, however assuming this is about the audit of a work item there is native support for this. The history tab provides nice workflow history supporting SSDLC processes.
Here is the MS specific documentation on history. You could filter via a query per person.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser